# How to handle Zend_Exception's in preDispatch or init of an action when using a base controller?

Tags: zend-framework, exception

As mentioned in the [Zend Framework manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.action.html), I created a base controller.

> Subclassing the Action Controller
>
> By design, Zend_Controller_Action must
>   be subclassed in order to create an
>   action controller. At the minimum, you
>   will need to define action methods
>   that the controller may call.
>
> Besides creating useful functionality
>   for your web applications, you may
>   also find that you're repeating much
>   of the same setup or utility methods
>   in your various controllers; if so,
>   creating a common base controller
>   class that extends
>   Zend_Controller_Action could solve
>   such redundancy.

But it turns out, that Exceptions are not being called properly from the base... To replicate this, create a file:

/path/to/workspace/library/Joe/Controller.php

Then:

```
class Joe_Controller extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function init()
    {
        Throw new Zend_Exception('test', 500);
        parent::init();
    }
}
```

Then in your controller directory, IndexController.php extends off the base:

```
class IndexController extends Joe_Controller
{
```

You will find that the exception is uncaught.

If however, you don't extend off the base controller, then throw an exception in init or preDispatch, it will be caught and forwarded to the ErrorController.

Anyone have an idea on getting the exceptions caught from the Base Controller?

Thanks.

**UPDATING TO TACKLE THIS ANOTHER WAY**

After looking at the various articles and official documentation on how to structure the directories, I went with putting the base controller in library/Joe/...but maybe that's part of the problem...there's no guidance in the manual on how to name and place the base controller. What do the experts with a base controller do?

**Another Update**

Looking at my code some more, and reading on the net, seems like people suggested in should be:

abstract class Joe_Controller_Action extends Zend_Controller_Action.

Except changing it did not solve the problem...

Now considering that there are articles suggesting to use Base Controllers including the manual, would this be considered a bug in Zend Framework?

To replicate, just throw a Zend_Exception of any kind in the base init or preDispatch. Imagine you poll the database in there, (which is what I'm doing)...and the database is down. No error controller. That's not a good situation unless I'm doing something incorrectly.

My suspicion is that this is a new bug... I don't recall this problem before Zend_Application and I've been using a base controller since ZF 1.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two thoughts off the top of my head:

1. Controller names in the default module are usually named like `SomethingController`. Your name `Joe_Controller` suggests the module `Joe` and an *empty* controller name.
2. In routing/dispatch, doesn't it look for a matching *action* before dispatch to the controller? Since the samples have no actions, might you be triggering ControllerNotFound exception?

Just throwin' out some ideas.

Comment: Thanks for helping me think this through! (Having trouble formatting the carriage returns so I'll move each point to a new comment).

Comment: 1. I just changed the name to Joe_BaseController and the code does talk to the ErrorController because although I changed IndexController to extend from Joe_BaseController, I had forgotten to change ErrorController and received an include error. But after fixing it, I still get uncaught exception. :(

Comment: After actually playing with some code, it all works for me: exception thrown, caught by the ErrorController. See pastie at http://pastie.org/1177214. Whaddya think is going on? Something different in the environment?

Comment: Finally have some time in front of the computer to play with this...I'm pretty sure it's an issue with ErrorController extending off Joe_Controller causing recursion problem. I'll come back with some more specific reply soon.

Comment: David, OK that fixed it. So the answer basically is that the error controller can't extend from the base controller...and if you need functionality from the base in the error controller, you need to use an Action helper.

Comment: That must be it. Yep, my ErrorController was the default one, extending Zend_Controller_Action. Your idea to use action helpers to get re-usable functionality in the ErrorController seems the right approach. Hey, I should be accepting your answer! ;-) Thanks and cheers.

Answer (score 0):

in Zend philosophy, they provide the init() method to avoid the hassle of

```
public class Module_TotoController extends Zend_Action_Controller {

    public function __construct(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request, Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract $response, array $invokeArgs = array())
        parent::__construct($request, $response, invokeArgs);

        // some init code here
    }
}
```

just use :

```
public class Module_TotoController extends Zend_Action_Controller {

    public function init ()
        // some init code here
    }
}
```

Now, If you look at the `Zend_Controller_Action` class source, you will notice that the following methods are **empty**:

- `init()`
- `preDispatch ()`
- `postDispatch ()`

This means, it is useless to call **`parent::`** in your specific controller

```
public class Module_TotoController extends Zend_Action_Controller {

    public function init ()
        parent::init(); // useless ;-) but you can go for it 

        // some init code here
    }
}
```

---

Now, if you want to put an intermediate class between `Module_TotoController` and `Zend_Action_Controller`, you expose yourself to a big hassle as:

- Some controllers won't extend your "base" controller (e.g your ErrorController in your question)

  - so it is not a really a base of your application, is it ?
- If you put some logic in your init() of that "base",

  - you must call the `parent::` in your `init()`,
  - all the developers in the project need to be aware of that
- You will ever add another little features to your "Base" controller

  - This will result to a big bloated file
  - Loading/Initializing plenty of stuff you might not really need in that lambda controller

    - Do you need you database on every page ?

      - No: doesn't a `$this->_helper->connect();` look nice instead ?
      - Yes: use a controller plugin
- This "Base" controller won't fit your other projects needs, so that class won't be reusable

  - Action helpers will
  - Controller Plugins will

Hope it makes sense

Comment: Thanks for your post Julien. Some great points. Just to be clearer, I agree with you. They need to remove that paragraph from the documentation. The new idea of using the helpers is superior. But I just followed the prevailing suggestions when first learning Zend Framework and there's now plenty of legacy code for me to support. That's why I chose to keep the base controller. If I started a new project, the Base would be gone. But changing old code means refactoring a bunch of controllers that currently work just fine....possibly introducing bugs...not to mention investment of time.

Answer (score -1):

Don't go for a base or whatever controller

As documentation says :

> By design, Zend_Controller_Action must be subclassed in order to create an action controller.

Agreed, this is misleading
What they meant is

`class Module_TotoController extends Zend_Controller_Action {}`

`class Module_TotoController extends Joe_Controller` is plain wrong (sorry no offence)

as you said your `ErrorController` can't extend your intermediate `Joe_Controller` class
because your exception will be thrown again in the instantiation of the `ErrorController` class (as excepted !!!)

The `uncaught Exception` error is the result of a protection to avoid loops (dig `Zend\Controller\Plugin\ErrorHanlder.php` line 200-ish)

If you require something to be done for every action, use a `Zend_Controller_Plugin` and register it with the frontController

Comment: Hi Julien, If you continued reading my quote, the next paragraph says clearly: "you may also find that you're repeating much of the same setup or utility methods in your various controllers; if so, creating a common base controller class that extends Zend_Controller_Action could solve such redundancy." They clearly say that a common base controller class is a good solution. And it was being said more often around ZF 1.5 when I started doing so. Now they are suggesting Plugins which I agree are better. But per Adrien's suggestion (offline), I started overriding init & preDispatch which fixed it

Comment: I will check out that ErrorHandler though...Thanks for the lead. Joe.